# How to set schema for entire query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working within a database that has multiple schemas(users) - in SQL DEVELOPER (ORACLE)

I would like to initially set a schema for my query, so that I won't need to include the schema name before every table that is written into the query.

Looking for:

```
USE SCHEMA_NAME;
SELECT * FROM TABLE;
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can set a different default schema using `alter session`:

```
alter session set current_schema = SCOTT;
```

This means we can reference objects in SCOTT's schema without prefixing them with SCOTT. That is, instead of `scott.emp` we can just:

```
select * from emp;
```

Note that we now need to prefix objects in our own schema:

```
select * from my.table_1;
```

Also, in case it isn't clear, setting `current_schema` doesn't confer any privileges: if SCOTT hasn't granted INSERT on EMP or SELECT on SALGRADE to us we can't use this technique to gain elevated access.